# RCA and S-video Splitter

Tags: cables, rca

I would like to split yellow RCA cable (because I need 2 input cables for 2 tvs/monitors). And do the same for S-video cable.
Can I use cheap simple "splitting" cables with one input and two outputs for this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, although at a loss in signal quality. It may be very small. If the connectors are poor or there's too much cable length, it will be noticable.

If the quality is too poor, consider an amplifier: http://forum.starmen.net/forum/General/Tech/Splitting-Composite-Video